# Unable to load Applet in WEB application. Getting ClassNotFoundException ImageDecodeParam

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I'm trying to load an applet in a html and it always throws ClassNotFoundException com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecodeParam. This applet runs fine as standalone application.
I tried adding the dependencies jai_codec.jar and Jai_core.jar in WEB-INF/lib and even along with the ImageViewer.jar. But its not at all recognizing. 
The applet code is

```
<body>
<APPLET code="ImageFrame.class" name="ImageFrame" codebase="viewer" archive="ImageViewer.jar"
    width=300 height=300>
  </APPLET>
<form name="taskForm" method="post" style="font: sans-serif"><br>
```

The Error logs

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at ImageFrame.init(ImageFrame.java:88)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/jai/codec/ImageDecodeParam
    at ImageFrame.imageZoom(ImageFrame.java:118)
    at ImageFrame$1.run(ImageFrame.java:93)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecodeParam
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: did you declare the dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF file of the ImageViewer.jar?

Comment: I have mentioned ** Class-Path: ./ jai_codec.jar jai_core.jar ** in manifest.mf of my jar still its not reading it.

Comment: Did you try to add it to the archive attribute in the HTML tag? Like `archive="ImageViewer.jar,jai_codec.jar,jai_core.jar"`